# Why python program runs slower in mac os terminal than in virtual machine(ubuntu)?

Tags: python, macos, performance, ubuntu

I wrote a simple program like this:

```
for i in range(0,10000000):
    x = i + 1
```

After I ran this program several times in Mac os's terminal and in Ubuntu's Terminal(which is a virtual machine in the Mac os), it turned out that mac os took 1.5 min and ubuntu only took 0.8 min.

I have no idea at all why this happened.
Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: are they both using the same verison of python? If your mac is running python2 it could be because python3 range() is equivlent to python2 xrange()

Comment: @Keatinge thank u for reply. and yes, python version is totally the same, both are python 2.7

Comment: try using xrange() instead of range and see if you get the same discrepenacies

Comment: when i changed range to xrange, mac took 1.2min and ubuntu almost the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it is may be because of the version you are using. Try to get latest versions of both Mac and Python or Python version compatible with your OSx.

Comment: Use Python 3.4 version with 10.9 OSx